# Why is there not a wiki on pipes?

Tags: c, wiki, pipe

I am reading the C programing guide and all of a sudden it starts talking about pipes.  Can someone simply tell me what a pipe is.

Comment: Could be http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe

Comment: Does it start talking about pipes in some sort of context? If so, that might help make your question clearer. If the book just starts saying "Pipes. Pipes! PIPES!" then perhaps the author was having a breakdown after a nasty plumbing accident.

Comment: funny! : ) no it says "it pipes the standard output" or "will write the standard ouput to outfile instead. If pipes are supported"

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_%28Unix%29

Comment: I think the question and the title refer to two different things. This question would be better if the two agreed on what is being asked. Are you really asking why there is no wiki about pipes, or are you asking what pipes are in the context of C programming?

Comment: The reason why there is no tag wiki for [pipe] is that none of the [20 empowered users](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/wiki/topusers) has gotten around to writing it (and it's not obvious who those folks are without looking). But there is an added complication that they words describes several different types of objects depending on the OS and context.

Comment: Well, I was kind of asking both questions, but more importantly I wanted to know what a pipeline was?  I think there are enough answers and links now to better my understanding.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are OS objects appearing as file descriptors in different processes, allowing output of one to be the input of the other. Read [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_%28Unix%29).

Answer (score 0):

You want to read [Beej's IPC Guide](http://beej.us/guide/bgipc/), specifically the pipe section.

> There is no form of IPC that is simpler than pipes. Implemented on every flavor of Unix, pipe() and [fork()](http://beej.us/guide/bgipc/output/html/multipage/fork.html) make up the functionality behind the "|" in "**ls | more**". They are marginally useful for cool things, but are a good way to learn about basic methods of IPC.

*Also check the other guides at http://beej.us/guide/.*

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, this means a Pipeline as in the context of Unix-like operating systems, see [Pipeline (Unix)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_%28Unix%29) in Wikpedia.  It is a chain of processes with the output of one process being the input to the next one.